# About Joomla Registration Form

Tags: joomla, registration

I'm using Joomla template... and I want to to register new user in it, but the problem is that whenever I create a new account and input all the fields and click on submit button the whole form is reset and no registration take place so help me out of this problem...

Comment: can u explain what do u mean by using a joomla template to register a new user.

Comment: i mean that there is a login module included in joomla template and when i created a new user it not working

Comment: What are you using to create a user. Have you used joomla backend to create a new user.

Comment: No, On Frontend http://www.box.net/shared/hgfojnbtdu

Comment: @Waqas i guess somebody has to look into what is exactly happening out there wid the code.

Comment: A good start would be to give us an address so that we at least can check out the HTML and JavaScript source.

Comment: Are you using the core Joomla registration page or a 3rd party module? How are you creating the link to the page? Does it work if you switch to one of the core templates? A link to the actual site would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check if new user registration is enabled in back-end settings. To do that - go to admin control panel, select Site > Global Configuration > System and check Allow User Registration parameter.